# jQuery $.post returning Object length: 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a pagination script using AJAX, but it refuses to grab the correct ID. My code here

```
$(document).on('click','#pagination a',function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');

    var $content = '.everything';

    $.post(link+'', function(data){
        var $new_content = $($content,data);
        console.log($new_content);
    },'html');
});
```

This is returning the following in my console:

```
Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: undefined, selector: ".everything" }
```

The object `.everything` most definitely exists in my DOM, as the item appears if I just `console.log(data);`. The element contains about 2000 characters.

The issue doesn't happen when I try to grab an element with less content by doing `console.log($('.logo',data));`

Comment: Is the element with `class="everything"` the outermost element in the data that you get back?

Comment: what is it that you get in `data` in the post success callback ?

Comment: @v0wels: It works with the `'.logo'` selector because the element is deep in the tree. It's when it's the outermost element that you can't find it, because it's only looking inside that element.

Comment: Can you share your thoughts behind this concatenation `link+''`?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you look for elements in the HTML snippet, it will look inside the outermost element.

For example `$('span', '<div><span></span></div>')` returns a jQuery object containing the `span` element, but `$('div', '<div><span></span></div>')` returns an empty jQuery object.

If you want to include the outermost element in the search, wrap it in another element:

```
var elements = $('<div>').append(data);
var $new_content = elements.find($content);
console.log($new_content);
```

Comment: I'm going to shoot myself. Thanks so much for your explanation!